# What symbol is used to go from common time to half time?

Tags: notation, time-signatures

What symbol do I use to go from common time to half time when notating that particular change?

Answer (score 5):

To change the meter, use whatever symbol denotes the meter you want to change to.  To change the tempo, you can either use numerical metronome marks or give a relative indication.

So if you start in 4/4 or  ("common time" symbol), and you want to switch to 2/2 or  ("cut time" symbol), and you want the half note in 2/2 to be as fast as the quarter note in 4/4, you can start with =80 (quarter=80) and then use =80 (half note=80 -- or whatever actual tempo you want).  A problem with the traditional approach of equating the half note with the quarter note is that practice has changed over the years as to whether one should write = (half=quarter) or = (quarter=half).  In this case it's unlikely to be ambiguous, but in some cases it can be.

Comment: The music symbols you've used seem to be system dependent. On my Mac, they all just show up as boxes of horizontal lines.

Comment: @Aaron I copied and pasted unicode characters into my browser.  Perhaps try a different font with support for musical symbols?  I'll check them on my desktop machine in a few minutes after my meeting.

Comment: @Aaron they work fine on my mac.

Comment: My point is that there will be readers who can't see those characters. They may or may not work on your desktop and @ElementsinSpace's Mac, but they will still remain a problem for others.

Comment: @Aaron the problem may lie in the fact that the musical symbols' numerical values are all greater that 65536, so they all require two 16-bit code units in UTF-16.  Or it could be font support.

Comment: Yeah, horizontal lines for me on Mac OS, both Chrome and Safari, and also on iOS, Chrome and Safari. I wonder whether it depends on having installed something like Finale or Sibelius on your machine?

Comment: I notice that [the wikipedia article *Alla breve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alla_breve) simply drops an svg into the text.

Comment: @AndyBonner interesting, I hadn't noticed that when I looked at it a few days ago; I just attributed the odd alignment and anomalous size to whatever it is that gives these symbols the odd alignment and small size they have on this site.  By contrast, they look pretty good in Consolas, albeit rather plainer than usual because it's a sans-serif font.

Comment: It's a font substitution issue - if you've installed 'scoring' software, your subs will probably be fine. Regular macOS cannot see it, so it drops the 'wtf emoji' symbol instead. The first symbol shows as MUSICAL SYMBOL COMMON TIME U+1D134 but I don't have a font that can display it. I've had this issue before in SE Q/As, the only real 'fix' is to drop tiny PNG files into your answer instead.